# How often can I castle?

Tags: rules, castling

I am learning to play chess on my computer. I have learned approximately all the rules but one rule stays vague for me thus far.

My questions are clear, though. I am putting them separated below with some little additions.

1. This is simple. **How often can I castle?** One time, two times, x
   times or till the end? I know that it can be executed if a rook and
   king are at their original places.
2. If I am allowed to castle one time, does that imply that I can make it two times because number of rooks for each player is 2?

Comment: @gatherer818 it doesn't have the answer for this question.

Comment: The question you r talking about should not have been asked since whatever is allowed in castling, can easily be found on internet. I have already searched hard to get answer to my question.

Comment: That question's answer pretty clearly states "You have not yet moved your King." as a requirement to castle, ergo, you can only castle once.  This is the same rule cited by the only answer to this question.  (I was in the middle of answering this question on Arqade when it was migrated, but here on Chess.SE this question has been answered a few times.  See also: http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/how-to-castle-2-times-in-a-game )

Comment: The problem came up because there is written that We can castle if king and rook are at their original places.

Comment: See also this question http://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/how-to-castle-2-times-in-a-game and its answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only castle once ever.  Part of the rule for castling is that you can only castle if your king has not moved.  So obviously you can never castle again, because castling entails moving your king.

Comment: Are you sure? There is written that castling can be done when king and rook are at their original places. Of course I can regain their original places.

Comment: This answer is correct, @SufyanNaeem

Comment: Votes show the degree of rightness and wrongness of an answer. I was therefore not accepting it but I have just read it in many answers as same and your reputation suggests that this is the perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: Of course I am sure -- I've been playing chess for over 45 years.  Again, my answer states that *part* "of the rule for castling is that you can only castle if your king has not moved".  So regardless of king and rook regaining their original squares, the king has already moved.

Answer (score 9):

FIDE Laws of Chess:

> 3.8.b.1. The right to castle has been lost: a) **if the king has already moved**, or b) with a rook that has already moved.

Emphasis mine.

Comment: Here's an example of castling happening 3 times in one game: 
[Heidenfeld - Kerins, Dublin 1973](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/recordstxt.htm#greatest%20number%20of%20castlings).

 I guess the rules only apply to those who follow them :)